# LocationComponent com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.getLocationComponent()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, mapbox-android

*Hey I'm doing a mapbox uber app. The rider and driver app used to work properly but for the past few days I'm getting a null error on the LocationCompoment ..can you guys help me to understand what is happening?
Here is the code :*

```
private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {

        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
    
            // Get an instance of the component
            LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
                         if (locationComponent != null){
            // Activate with options
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(
LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(this, loadedMapStyle).build());
    
            // Enable to make component visible
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
    
            // Set the component's camera mode
            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
    
            // Set the component's render mode
            locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);
       } } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have two `if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this))` checks? You only need one.

Set up your project to match https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/show-a-users-location/, which is the most basic way to show the device location.

You could also do a null check after `LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();`

Comment: Hey sir , yes he Does like he use too .. i notice that the problem is the implementation of Onesignal Api , in that process of installing oneSignal Api i did face many kind of error like {use of Deprecated Api and Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 65575 > 65536)
} so i did made the MultiDexEnabled That is when i started getting a null reference for the locationcomponent ..i may think that i shall use FCM from firebase than Onesignal